# How to access a button inside a listview? specifically using the button_click to carry out an action

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have this simplified code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldatasource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonTest" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" Text="Add to Cart" />
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:ListView>
```

I am trying to run some code behind the button but I don't know how. I can't access it within the listview. Not that this is important, but im trying to get information from the current listview(the product ID) and pass it to the next page.

Anybody know how to approach this, with the exact code? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want the `ItemCommand` event.  You would give your button a command name, a command argument (if you want), then listen for the ItemCommand event on the ListView

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DoTheCommand" DataSourceID="sqldatasource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button CommandName="Foo" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SomeDataBoundProperty")%>' ID="ButtonTest" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" Text="Add to Cart" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And in your code behind:

```
void DoTheCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    string commandName = e.CommandName;
    object commandArg = e.CommandArgument;
    ListViewItem selectedItem = e.Item;
    int dataItemIndex = selectedItem.DataItemIndex;

    if (commandName == "Foo") {
         //and so on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use ListView's ItemCommand Event in codebehind with commandName and command argument set in aspx.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldatasource1">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" CommandName="cAdd" CommandArgument= '<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' Text="Add to Cart" />
```

```
Protected Sub ListView1_OnItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles Listview1.ItemCommand

If String.Equals(e.CommandName, "cAdd") Then

 Dim ProductId as integer = e.CommandArgument

 'your code
 End If

End Sub
```